# Is it okay to use a `onclick` function to make a login page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

I'm still learning so please excuse me if this is an incorrect practice. I'm trying to make a login page using JSP and was wondering if it's alright to make the user validation through AJAX via an onclick function instead of using `forms`

This is the code I tried.

```js
function login() {

  var modelObj = {

    username: $("#username").val(),
    password: $("#password").val()
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8092/api/loginuser",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(modelObj),
    success: function(data) {
    
      console.log("POST API RESPONSE::" + data);

      if (data === "1") {
        window.location = "/homepage.jsp"

      } else if (data === "0") {
        alert("Incorrect username or password")
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" />
<input type="text" placeholder="password" id="password" />
<input type="button" value="login" onclick="login()" />
```

Appreciate any tips I can use in case there's a better way to do it. (Tried searching and most of them lead to using PHP, but I'm trying to use this in a JSP)

Comment: Yes , it is okay to do validation via ajax  .

Comment: @Swati That's a relief. Thank you